# ¿Como hacer que no se repita una pregunta de un Arraylist?

Tags: kotlin

Estoy creando una **app** de preguntas y respuestas, cada pregunta aparece de manera "**aleatoria**" pero necesito que al aparecer dicha pregunta, no sea repetida, como podría hacer eso en mi método `getPregunta()`?

acá les dejo mi clase:

**Preguntas.kt**

```
 class Preguntas {
    private var listaP = Array(3){ arrayOfNulls<String>(5)}
    private var numeroRandom = 0
    init {
        listaP[0][0] = "¿Cuál la capital de Italia?"
        listaP[0][1] = "Roma"
        listaP[0][2] = "Benesia"
        listaP[0][3] = "Parma"
        listaP[0][4] = "Milan"

        listaP[1][0] = "¿En que año nació Diego Armando Maradona?"
        listaP[1][1] = "1960"
        listaP[1][2] = "1959"
        listaP[1][3] = "1961"
        listaP[1][4] = "1962"

        listaP[2][0] = "¿Cuál es la capital de Brasil"
        listaP[2][1] = "Brasilia"
        listaP[2][2] = "Rio de Janeiro"
        listaP[2][3] = "Sao Pablo"
        listaP[2][4] = "Porto Alegre"

        val random = Random()
        numeroRandom = random.nextInt(3)
    }

    fun getPregunta() : ArrayList<String?>{
        val listaPreguntas = ArrayList<String?>()
        listaPreguntas.add(listaP[numeroRandom][0])
        return listaPreguntas
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el metodo .contains() del objeto ArrayList para comprobar si ya contiene un elemento antes de añadirlo a la lista